# Writing Form Submit to Text File

Tags: php

I have a simple form that echos a value on submit using form. I want this value to be written to a text file, I cant seem to figure out why my code is not working any ideas?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) { 
$txt=$_POST['button1']; 
file_put_contents('status.txt',$txt,FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX); 
exit();
}
?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    Restaurant Open:
    <input type="radio" name="button1" value="Open" onClick="submit();" <?php echo       ($_POST['button1'] == 'Open') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> Open                            
<input type="radio" name="button1" value="Closed" onClick="submit();" <?php echo                ($_POST['button1'] == 'Closed') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/> Closed
    </form> 

<?php

 if (isset($_POST['button1']) == 'Open')
 echo "Open Today.";

 else if (isset($_POST['button1']) == 'Closed')
 echo "Closed Today.";

 ?>
```

Comment: It seems that on submit everything disappears

Comment: UPDATE: actually it does write to the text file, just not sure why my form disappears

Comment: The form itself disappears

Comment: look at your echo `echo  ($_POST['button1'] == 'Open') ? 'checked="checked"' : '';` no sense, don't think so?

Comment: Of course the form disappears. You have an `exit;` in your code if the post is submitted.

Comment: because you `exit()` after writing to the file

Comment: TRUE ENOUGH! Figured it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The form disappears because you [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) before writing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this code.

on the radio button, I changed

`<?php echo       ($_POST['button1'] == 'Open') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>`

into

`if($_POST['button1'] == 'Open') echo "checked=checked"; ?>`

which will avoid misunderstood.

```
  <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['button1'])) { 
    $txt=$_POST['button1']; 
    file_put_contents('status.txt',$txt,FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX); 
    //removed exit
    }
    ?>

<form method="post" action="">
    Restaurant Open:
<input type="radio" name="button1" value="Open" onClick="submit();" <? if($_POST['button1'] == 'Open') echo "checked=checked"; ?> /> Open                            
<input type="radio" name="button1" value="Closed" onClick="submit();" <? if($_POST['button1'] == 'Closed') echo "checked=checked"; ?> /> Closed
</form> 

    <?php

     if ($_POST['button1'] == 'Open')
     echo "Open Today.";

     elseif ($_POST['button1'] == 'Closed')
     echo "Closed Today.";
     else
     echo "Choose a status.";

     ?>
```

Comment: Could you add some description to your answer, to explain what changes you've made and why?

Comment: Also, isset won't return the value, only a boolean. So it would be wise to fix that as well

Comment: I made some changement, be aware of it !

Comment: There should be `$_session[];` used to save the values.